# Django/Wagtail Model Admin fields not showing in API

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I am using wagtail and I have a ModelAdmin called `sorting`. I have a `PageChooserPanel` inside the ModelAdmin. I have exposed these in API but it's showing only id of the table but not showing full details. But in my database, I can view them.

[image: Database]

API Response
[image]

Models screenshot

[image: screenshot1]

[image]

Here is my `views.py`

class FeaturedList(APIView):

```
def get(self, request):
    featured =Featured.objects.all()
    serializer= FeaturedSerializer(featured, many = True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class FeaturedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Featured
        fields = ("featured_name","featured_pages",)
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.models import Page, Orderable
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from blog.models import *
from wagtail.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.panels import PageChooserPanel, FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalManyToManyField

class IDChoice(models.IntegerChoices):
    Featured1 = 0, _('Featured1')
    Featured2 = 1, _('Featured2')
    Featured3 = 2, _('Featured3')
    Featured4 = 3, _('Featured4')
    Featured5 = 4, _('Featured5')

class Featured(ClusterableModel):
    featured_name = models.IntegerField(default=IDChoice.Featured1,choices=IDChoice.choices, blank=True, null=False, help_text='Featured ID', unique=True)
    panels = [
        InlinePanel('featured_pages', label="Featured pages"),
        FieldPanel('featured_name'),
    ]


class FeaturedPages(Orderable, models.Model):
    """
    Orderable helper class, and what amounts to a ForeignKey link
    to the model we want to add featured pages to (Featured)
    """

    featured_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    featured_item = ParentalKey(
        Featured,
        related_name='featured_pages',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('featured_page'),
    ]
    def __str__(self):
        """String repr of this class."""
        return self.featured_page

    class Meta:  # noqa
        verbose_name = "Featured"
        verbose_name_plural = "Featured Stories"
```

`admin.py`

```
from .models import *
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register,)

class SortingAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Featured
    menu_lebel= "Sorting"
    menu_icon = "placeholder"
    menu_order = 290
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    list_display = ("featured_name","featured_pages")
    search_field = ("featured_name","featured_pages")

modeladmin_register(SortingAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change a little bit in my `serializers.py` file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Featured, FeaturedPages

class FeaturedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FeaturedPages
        fields = ("featured_item","sort_order","featured_page",)
```

`views.py`

```
class FeaturedList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        featured =FeaturedPages.objects.all()
        serializer= FeaturedSerializer(featured, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now everything coming same as DB.